# C# EF Code first - create database and add data

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I want to create database and add some data. I added EF and I want to use code first. I have these classes:

```
public class Question
{
    public bool Sort { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Answer1 { get; set; }
    public string Answer2 { get; set; }
    public string Answer3 { get; set; }
    public string Answer4 { get; set; }
    public string RightAnswer { get; set; }
    public bool Show { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="ConvertCSVtoSQL.QuestionDb" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|ConvertCSVtoSQL.QuestionDb.sdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

Now I am creating database like this:

```
using (var db = new QuestionDb())
        {

            foreach (var question in questions)
            {
                db.Questions.Add(question);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

It creates database but if I have some data in questions which I want to add I get error:

> The Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices,
>   EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' for the 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'
>   ADO.NET provider could not be loaded. Make sure the provider assembly
>   is available to the running application. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

I tried to add some initializers but it didn't help:

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0",@"C:\Path\To\",@"Data Source=C:\Path\To\DbFile.sdf");
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<QuestionDb>());
```

So where is problem?

Comment: Proberly your connectionstring that makes the error. Check "mvc music store" and see how he did.

Comment: So did you visit the link in the exception message? What you tried does not seem to be inspired by that.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I don't find any useful information but I looked there and I added EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact package by Nuget and It helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at link in exception, add nuget package EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact to my solution and it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the connection string's provider name...

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/08/announcing-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-release.aspx

Hope you may find this useful

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0",@"C:\\Path\To\\",@"Data Source=C:\\Path\\To\\DbFile.sdf");
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<QuestionDb>());
```

Comment: When I change provider name to: `System.Data.SqlClient`  I get this error: `An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.`

Comment: Please try this way...`Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0",@"C:\\Path\\To\\",@"Data Source=C:\\Path\To\\DbFile.sdf");
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<QuestionDb>());`

Answer (score 1):

Running following Command in VS Package manager Console resolved my  issue:

Install-Package EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact -Pre